# Export nested list with complex structure

Tags: export, list-manipulation

I have a list that looks like this

```
l = {elem1, elem2, ...}
```

Where `elem_={t, {d1,d2,d3} }`

How can I export it? I tried `Export["data.txt",l,"Table"]`, but it puts a whole `elem` on the same line so the nested structure can't be restored. I suppose I could write a function to parse the txt file, but what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: ExportString[{ {t, {d1, d2, d3}}}, "Package"] or you use Put or Save

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do, for example, the following:

```
list = Table[{i, {2^i, 3^i, 5^i}}, {i, 1, 10}]
```

then

```
Export["test.m", list]
```

and

```
Clear @ list
```

and finally

```
list = Import["test.m"]
```